# SQL Max(integer) without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have large tables where data quality rules are running. There is a field called "RunNumber" to identify if data is appended- it can have a value of 1 or 2(but not limited to just 2). We don't have a Group By statement. Searching here, I found questions titled "SQL Max(date) without group by" and "SQL max without group by", and tried putting the MAX statement as below, but don't think that it's working correctly because of the output. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
    MAX(RunNumber),
    CAST(SUM(FirstName) AS INT) AS FirstName,
    CAST(SUM(LastName) AS INT) AS LastName,
    CAST(SUM(State) AS INT) AS State
FROM
    (SELECT
         CASE WHEN FirstName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FirstName,
         CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END LastName,
         CASE WHEN State IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END State
     FROM 
         Table.Customers (nolock)
     WHERE 
         DateOfRecord = '5/1/2023') a;
```

The output that I get is:

| [No name 1] | FirstName | LastName | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5000 | 7500 | 9000 |

Comment: can you show example data?

Comment: That query can't produce that result, `a` has no column `RunNumber` defined. The query would error.

Comment: Please show; sample data, desired results and actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select MaxRun    = MAX(RunNumber)
      ,FirstName = sum( case when FirstName is null then 1 else 0 end)
      ,LastName  = sum( case when LastName  is null then 1 else 0 end)
      ,[State]   = sum( case when [State]   is null then 1 else 0 end)
 From Table.Customers
 Where DateOfRecord = '2023-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood something from your question, you want to do calculations for each RunNumber

```
SELECT
        RunNumber,
         FirstName,
         LastName,
         State

FROM
(
    SELECT
            SUM(CASE WHEN FirstName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over( partition by RunNumber order by (select 1)) FirstName,
            SUM(CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over( partition by RunNumber order by (select 1)) LastName,
            SUM(CASE WHEN State IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over( partition by RunNumber order by (select 1)) State
            ,RunNumber 
            ,ROW_NUMBER()  over( partition by RunNumber order by (select 1)) as rw
    FROM Customers (nolock)
    WHERE DateOfRecord = '5/1/2023'
)a
where a.rw=1
```

Base Data:

```
create table Customers(FirstName nvarchar(100),LastName nvarchar(100),State int,
DateOfRecord date,RunNumber int)
insert into Customers values('aa',null,null,'5/1/2023',0)
,(null,'bb',null,'5/1/2023',0),(null,'tt',null,'5/1/2023',1),('ss',null,null,'5/1/2023',1)
```

Comment: Quite the opposite- i wanted to only perform the calculations on the MAX RunNumber.